# trouble with font size for different screen size/resolution

Tags: android

I know this has been answered in other questions, but nothing is working for me.  I have a text view where I want the text to appear the same size in a variety of density/screen size combinations.  I have tried specifying

```
android:textSize="30dp"
```

and

```
android:textSize="30sp"
```

and have also used

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setTextSize(30 * (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
```

30 is my font size *******

the text doesn't scale properly.  It becomes way too small at lower densities and as screen size increases.  Are there additional techniques I can use to scale my font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create layout-large, layout-small, layout-xlarge etc.. versions of your layout xml file.

You can set the size differently in each so that the font will look right across a variety of screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks Foamy.  Since this one font size is the only thing I'm having trouble with, is it possible to avoid duplicating the entire layout in each folder and abstract away just the textSize?

Comment: I'm not certain. If so it will probably involve Styles and/or Themes. Search around on the dev site for stuff related to those.

Answer (score 0):

After years of constantly having everything slightly off on different devices, I recently discovered that the inches and cm measurements for dimensions are literally that.

So even on devices where 160dp isn't quite an inch, specifying 1inch will give exactly that, on everything, even if they have a custom scaled ROM.

I now specify anything I want very tight control over with these.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have separate font sizes for separate screens, you can create dimens in your value.xml for sw600dp and sw720dp folder too and put different values there. You don't need to create separate xml layout for each, if you just need to change font sizes.